# SQL Server 2012 data striping

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Is data striping possible like mentioned here [data striping in older SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187087%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
in the newest version of SQL Server like SQL Server 2012?

I know this is possible in 2008 and 2008R2.

Comment: Yes, why would you think this capability would disappear? Here is the 2012 version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187087%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Okay thank, weird from that page I can navigate to previous versions but not vica versa. Well thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I've asked Microsoft why you have to manually change the URL to get to the 2012 version. 2012 is now the default, so you can also get to the 2012 version by removing the `(v=sql.xxx)` part of the string altogether, but SQL Server 2012 should be an option in the drop-down if that's not the version of the doc you're in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as reflected in my comments, this capability still exists in SQL Server 2012. There is just an issue in Books Online currently that makes it appear that there isn't a 2012 version of this topic, if the current version of the topic you're in is not the 2012 version.